# Get 2 counts in single query

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, group-by, aggregate

I need to get count of 2 columns with group by

[image]

This is my sample data

I need to get count of persons from particular state and count of persons from particular country

My output should be like

[image]

I need to manipulate data like this; how to create query for this

Comment: I do not see the values shown in desured result ('xxx' and other) for `country=234` in source data...

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT country, 
       COUNT(state) total,
       SUM(state='xxx') xxx,
       SUM(state='yyy') yyy,
       SUM(state='zzz') zzz
FROM table
GROUP BY country
```

Comment: I know it was not your intention, but for your information:`This answer was flagged as low-quality because of its length and content.`

Comment: @MarcelloMiorelli Thank you for this information. I know the resource doesn't care about helping people at all. They are only interested in beautiful and detailed answers, and their usefulness is not worth attention. If the question author will not understand something - I will explain further. But I'm not going to guess what he might not understand.